# Single Sign on for already existing multiple web applications

Tags: web-services, authentication, web, web-applications, single-sign-on

What would be the best way to implement single sign on for a group of web applications developed using different back end stacks without using any third part services and without taking them down. How can be the migration be done ?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. For single sign on to work, you must have same database table which contains username/password for all the web applications
> 2. Create and deploy a web service which has login method with two parameters username and password. This method authenticates user and returns user id and their respective role and login valid upto time.
>
>    if user is authenticated FIRST TIME, update valid upto time for that user into
>      database for which user will remain authenticated. e.g. 10 days from
>      now
>
>    If authentication fails, login method should return false
> 3. In each web applications, in webservice callable method, if user login is succeed, create a cookie which should be expired on validupto
>      time return by web service. Adjust cookie time as per server's timezone
> 4. let's guess, user is validated from web application1 and cookie is created which is not going to expired for the next 10 days as per
>      validupto time
> 5. Same user opens web application 2 who is not logged into web appliation2. Here you have to check whether login cookie is found or not, if not call webservice,
>
> webservice will check that user's validupto is  more than current time
>   from db so it will return user id and his respective role, validupto time directly without checking user's credentials 
>   So here again, cookie will be created based on validupto time returns by webservice which will
>
> expire on the same time as web application 1 cookie. So the same user will remain logged into both web application 1 & 2 for the same time.
>
> Once cookie is expired, user will be logged out from both web applications.
>
> This way, you can use as many web applications as you want for Single Sign On.
>
> NOTE: Make sure that you have same fuction in all web application which calls webservices and creates cookie based on web service response.

Comment: I just read about SAML and Oauth2.0. Was just thinking that, is there any way from which the various authentication servers can talk to each other and provide the authentication rather than having a single central authentication server.